# Is "cook the steak" correct?

Tags: word-choice, grammar, verbs

I was just asking [a question](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/14804/how-should-i-cook-the-steak-at-home) on Cooking Stack Exchange and I have written the following sentence:

> how should I cook the steak at home

Well, it looks wrong to me, but I couldn't find any alternative word for that. *Grill* might fit more here but I didn't mean that. What I was getting at is to express to make the steak eatable with pan and oven.

So what do you think?

Comment: here is the link of the question as well : http://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/14804/how-should-i-cook-the-steak-at-home

Comment: Related: _[Is it wrong to say “cook a cake”?](http://english.stackexchange.com/q/10900/5822)_

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Theoretically, *cooking* refers to any application of heat to food:

> **cook** |kʊk|
>   verb
>   1 [ trans. ] prepare (food, a dish, or a meal) by combining and heating the ingredients in various ways

<sup>*NOAD*</sup>

In practice, *cooking* usually refers to stovetop prepartation and *baking* refers to oven preparation. And each have their own more specific terms. *Frying* and *sautéing* are usually done stovetop and *broiling* and *roasting* are usually done inside the oven.

Comment: Yes, I'd suggest that if "cooking" the steak feels wrong, perhaps just "preparing" the steak would suit.

Answer (score 3):

Grilling a steak and cooking a steak both are correct, depends on what do you want to do exactly. or maybe you mean "Oven Baked Steak" to make the steak edible. Baking the steak until meat is tender!